# how to determine when the audio.play() is done playing mp3? lua

Tags: lua, mp3, coronasdk, duration

I have a problem in determining when the `audio.play()` method done in playing mp3 file.

i have this code ..

```
audio.play("HelloWorld.mp3", {onComplete=print ("Done!")})
```

but when the mp3 starts, it will also print `"Done!"`, i try also to put `Duration` but it will do the same.

i just want to print `"Done!"` when the mp3 is done playing. can anyone can help me about this?

and also how can I get the duration of an mp3 file in lua? in my case i just look-up to the mp3 file manually and input it in my code..

thanks in advance ...

Comment: Please could you change the music :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now i get it i just put...

```
local songCompleted = function(event)   
  if event.completed then   
    print ("Done!")
    ...
  end
end

audio.play("HelloWorld.mp3", {onComplete=songCompleted})
```